# does function_exists() cache its queries?

Tags: php, caching

I wonder to know does [function_exists()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) cache its queries internally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[No, it does not.](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/af6c11c5f060870d052a2b765dc634d9e47d0f18/Zend/zend_builtin_functions.c#L1359) It just checks whether the function is defined in the function table. Simple enough.

However, [the Zend Opcache extension may optimize out some calls to `function_exists()`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/e141592da6cdb15709e4aeaab5421c9a46564849/ext/opcache/Optimizer/pass1_5.c#L349) and certain other functions which can in some cases be evaluated at compile time. (It only optimizes out calls to `function_exists()` where the function is defined internally by PHP, or by an extension.)

Comment: Thanks, an outstanding answer, what do you think about my note down [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21619939/does-function-exists-cache-its-queries/21620859#21620859)?

Answer (score 0):

**No it doesn't**, the following performance tests are confirming the fact:

```
function function_exists_cached($function_name)
{
    static $cache = array();
    if(isset($cache[$function_name]))
        return $cache[$function_name];
    return ($cache[$function_name] = \function_exists($function_name));

}
$funcs = \array_shift(\get_defined_functions());
$a = new \core\utiles\loadTime;
$times = $tot = 0;
$a->start();
/**
 * None Cached: No cache used here
 **/
for($index = 0; $index<count($funcs); $index++)
{
    foreach($funcs as $func)
    {
        $times++;
        if(\function_exists($func)) ;
    }
}
$s = $a->stop();
$tot+=$s;
echo "<b>None Cached : </b><b><span style='color:green'>#$times</span></b> function check took : $s seconds<br />";
$b = new \core\utiles\loadTime;
$times = 0;
$b->start(); 
/**
 * Fly Cached: An inline cache used here
 **/
static $func_check = array();
for($index = 0; $index<count($funcs); $index++)
{
    foreach($funcs as $func)
    {
        $times++;
        if(!isset($func_check[$func]))
        {
            if(\function_exists($func)) ;
            $func_check[$func] = 1;
        }
        else $func_check[$func];
    }
}
$s = $b->stop();
$tot+=$s;
echo "<b>Fly Cached : </b><b><span style='color:green'>#$times</span></b> function check took : $s seconds<br />";
$c = new \core\utiles\loadTime;
$times = 0;
$c->start();
/**
 * Function Cached: Has the same logic like Fly Cached section, 
 * But implemented in a function named function_exists_cached()
 **/
for($index = 0; $index<count($funcs); $index++)
{
    foreach($funcs as $func)
    {
        $times++;
        if(\function_exists_cached($func)) ;
    }
}
$s = $c->stop();
$tot+=$s;
echo "<b>Function Cached : </b><b><span style='color:green'>#$times</span></b> function check took : $s seconds<br />";
echo "Total time : $tot seconds";
```

---

### outputs:

**None Cached :** **#2365444** function check took : 0.69758 seconds
**Fly Cached :** **#2365444** function check took : 0.5307 seconds
**Function Cached :** **#2365444** function check took : 1.02575 seconds
Total time : 2.25403 seconds

---

Again i wonder to know, considering that `function_exists_cached($function_name)` has the same implementation of **Fly Cached** code lines, why does it take that much time??

Comment: **why does it take that much time??** It's slower because of the overhead of a function call.